# FBSDKShareContent share local image

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-share, fbsdk

Trying to share local image via FBSDKShareLinkContent but without success.

My sample code is:

```
 let content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentTitle = "test share"
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com")
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testImage", ofType: "png")
    content.imageURL = NSURL(string: path!)
    let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    shareDialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Native
    shareDialog.shareContent = content
    shareDialog.fromViewController = self
    shareDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sharing Image you need to use `FBSDKSharePhotoContent`. Check the below code in Objective C

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
  photo.image = image;
  photo.userGenerated = YES;
  FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
  content.photos = @[photo];
  ...
}
```

Refer : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: I understand, But want to use local image to share instead of always download it from internet

Comment: your above code is to share the URL, in that you can't give the local file path.